# Characters are not flush left with \usepackage{droid} (but works with helvet)

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have observed that

```
Michael\\
Awa\\
Hans\\
Jürgen\\
Thomas\\
Hans\\
Peter\\
```

will produce the expected result when using

```
\usepackage{helvet}
```

however, with

```
\usepackage{droid}
```

the leftmost characters are not "flush left", in particular "J" and "A" start further left than "M" or "H". Can we improve on that?

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,13pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{droid} %!
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
1\\
Michael\\
Awa\\
Hans\\
Jürgen\\
Thomas\\
Hans\\
Peter\\
\end{document}
```

Many thanks in advance, 
 Stefan

[image: helvet]
[image: droid]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem shows also with Helvetica, but it seems that the side bearings of some letters in Droid are wider. You can see and compare the side bearings in the top part of the picture (Droid above, Helvetica below); the rule on the left is meant to illustrate the alignment of some uppercase letters. Note that J in Droid has the hook slightly outside the bounding box.

There's no way to access the side bearing in `pdftex`; it's possible for OpenType or TrueType fonts in XeTeX.

[image]

Here's the way with Xe(La)TeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setsansfont{Droid Sans}

\newcommand{\noleft}[1]{%
  \leavevmode\begingroup
  \edef\gid{\the\XeTeXcharglyph`#1}%
  \null\kern-\XeTeXglyphbounds 1 \gid
  #1%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\sffamily

\parbox[t]{1.5cm}{
\noindent\kern-0.1pt \smash{\vrule height 1.5ex depth 10cm width 0.1pt}%
\noleft{M}\\
\noleft{A}\\
\noleft{B}\\
\noleft{C}\\
\noleft{J}\\
\noleft{K}
}
\parbox[t]{1.5cm}{
\noindent\kern-0.1pt \smash{\vrule height 1.5 ex depth 10cm width 0.1pt}%
M\\
A\\
B\\
C\\
J\\
K
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are saying that pdftex is - in principle - not able to produce (really) flush left output with a font package like droid?

Comment: @StefanVollmar TeX makes flush left output; but if the characters are not flush with their bounding box…

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer above. So it seems that this is quite a show-stopper class problem with Droid and it definitely reduces the usefulness of that font with pdftex - what a pity. But - I have just tried XeTeX and changed the source to: [...] \usepackage{fontspec} \setsansfont{DroidSans} [...] and I am seeing exactly the same problem (after installing Droid in a TTF version). No hope?

Comment: @StefanVollmar I added the code for XeTeX

Comment: Excellent! This works for me - so I end up with something like `\noleft{H}ans` for all lines that should be (really) flush left, a reasonable workaround for my current use case. Thanks again - however, the feeling remains that something as fundamental as setting text flush left should be simpler.